# Eclipse spaces instead of tabs for aligning variable names and values, how?

Tags: java, eclipse, tabs, spaces

I like to use tabs for indention, since that way people can decide their own indention size. However, when using tabs for aligning anything, it will completely mess up the alignment when using a different tab size.

Take this code for example:

```
    public static final MailCostManager             mailCost            = new MailCostManager();
    public static final GamePricesManager           gamePrices          = new GamePricesManager();
    public static final GameNamesManager            gameNames           = new GameNamesManager();
    public static final GameInfoManager             gameInfo            = new GameInfoManager();
    public static final GameServerManager           gameServers         = new GameServerManager();
    public static final GameServerJoiningManager    gameServerJoining   = new GameServerJoiningManager();
    public static final MatchmakingManager          matchmaking         = new MatchmakingManager();
    public static final GroupManager                groups              = new GroupManager();
    public static final LevelManager                levels              = new LevelManager();
    public static final PaymentWallManager          paymentWall         = new PaymentWallManager();
    public static final HttpAccountActions          httpAccountActions  = new HttpAccountActions();
```

The indention (the tab before the "public static ...") should be a tab, since that is the indention. However, the space between the types and the variable names, and the variable names and the values, should be spaces.

How do I make Eclipse use spaces for aligning the variable names and values, and use tabs for indentation, including the indention of these variable lines?

Is this even possible with Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Eclipse can use tabs or spaces but it does not support mixing them like this.

Comment: Damn, that's too bad, since that would pretty much fix tab/space wars as far as I can see. Ah well, too bad, maybe one day.